# Downloading configuration data

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have an application attached to the configuration file:

```
{
  "ProjectModules": [
    {
      "Version": "1",
      "LoginModule": {
        "LoginLogic": "Project1.ModulesV1.LoginModule.Logic.LoginLogic"
      }
    },
    {
      "Version": "2",
      "LoginModule": {
        "LoginLogic": "Project1.ModulesV2.LoginModule.Logic.LoginLogic"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**How to get the value for the "LoginLogic" key and for a specific version?**

Here I started to do but it does not take into account that it is a data table

```
if (_configuration.GetSection("ProjectModules:" + moduleName).Exists())
{
    var configSection = _configuration.GetSection("ProjectModules:" + moduleName);

    if (configSection[sectionName] != null)
    {
        part = configSection[sectionName];
    }
}
```

EDIT:

- moduleName -> `LoginModule`
- sectionName -> `LoginLogic`

I need to get the value for the `"LoginLogic"` key knowing the version `"Version"`

Comment: There is no section named `"ProjectModules:" + moduleName` - just one named `ProjectModules`. Where do you get `moduleName` from and what is it? What is `sectionName`?

Comment: @fredrik I addded in description

Answer (score 1):

It's going to be extremely difficult, if not impossible, to do what you want with JSON formatted this way. You need to understand how the configuration system works. No matter what the config source (JSON, environment variables, console arguments, etc.) everything, and I mean everything ends up dumped into a dictionary. Pretty much the entire responsibility of a config provider is to take the source and convert it into a dictionary, which is then returned and merged into the main configuration dictionary.

As such, what you're actually creating here is:

```
["ProjectModules[0]:Version"] = 1
["ProjectModules[0]:LoginModule:LoginLogic"] = "Project1.ModulesV1.LoginModule.Logic.LoginLogic"
["ProjectModules[1]:Version"] = 2
["ProjectModules[1]:LoginModule:LoginLogic"] = "Project1.ModulesV2.LoginModule.Logic.LoginLogic"
```

As you can see, there's no real way here to tell exactly which version belongs to which `LoginLogic`, except for the index of `ProjectModules` being the same. However, since that's just a string serving as a key in the dictionary, it's not something you can easily filter or search on.

One option would be to change the format a bit if you can. For example, if you instead had JSON like:

```
{
  "ProjectModules": {
    "Version1": {
      "LoginModule": {
        "LoginLogic": "Project1.ModulesV1.LoginModule.Logic.LoginLogic"
      }
    },
    "Version2": {
      "LoginModule": {
        "LoginLogic": "Project1.ModulesV1.LoginModule.Logic.LoginLogic"
      }
    }
 }
```

}

Then, you'd end up with:

```
["ProjectModules:Version1:LoginModule:LoginLogic"] = "Project1.ModulesV1.LoginModule.Logic.LoginLogic"
["ProjectModules:Version2:LoginModule:LoginLogic"] = "Project1.ModulesV2.LoginModule.Logic.LoginLogic"
```

And, it's easy enough to distinguish then by version.